# Specify Twilio Region for Rest API

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

We are using the Twilio Programmable Voice Service globaly. In the US and EU the performance is acceptable. In Australia there is a long delay after the user answers the phone and before the user hears anything. I attempted to set the region using the C# SDK using the regions specified [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk/regions#region-information-for-programmable-voice-sdk). That essentially sets the root API url to https://api.au1.twilio.com which does not exists/respond (502 error). Has anyone had any success specifying the region for REST API calls using Twilio?

** I have tried using us1 and ie1 with the same results.

Comment: Please show us some code that you have implemented so far?

Comment: @KelvinLai - I have similar problem. Can you have a look on the code I am trying please ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56912640/twilio-how-to-create-turn-credentials-for-a-particular-region

Answer (score 0):

I received this from Twilio Support. It looks like server side API calls are US only.

> Thanks for writing and sorry for the trouble. I think where we're
>   getting stuck is the difference between the server-side helper library
>   concept of the HTTP client for making and responding to REST API
>   requests, and the voice over IP product Client and its associated
>   SDKs.
>
> The region can absolutely be set on the VoIP Client applications, and
>   we have this in place specifically to address the types of audio
>   latency you're describing below; the important distinction being that
>   the region designation happens at the local application, not in the
>   serve-side code. You can see how to set the region in the JavaScript
>   library, the Android SDK, and the iOS SDK.
>
> The reason this works for VoIP Client calls is that we have media
>   endpoint in those regions; however, we do not have regionalized API
>   endpoints--api.twilio.com is *only* located in the US, so trying to
>   create a TwilioRestClient for HTTP requests will not work.
>
> Hope that helps. Please let me know if you have any questions